# could not find http://master.dl.sourceforge.net/project/red-robot-editor/repository in ubuntu

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ubuntu-14.04

I want to add RED Robot Editor to eclipse in ubuntu
Help->Eclipse Marketplace->RED->Install
it is showing ERROR as
"No repository found at http://master.dl.sourceforge.net/project/red-robot-editor/repository. "
then i tried from Help go to Install new software. click Add,
updated site: http://master.dl.sourceforge.net/project/red-robot-editor/repository
and still it is showing error as "could not find  [http://master.dl.sourceforge.net/project/red-robot-editor/repository"](http://master.dl.sourceforge.net/project/red-robot-editor/repository%22).
Can someone help how to solve this.

Comment: Works for me. Are you behind a proxy or firewall? Can you access/download [this file](http://master.dl.sourceforge.net/project/red-robot-editor/repository/compositeContent.xml) from a web browser? Which Eclipse version do you have?

Comment: Eclipse version :Luna Service Release 2(4.4.2)
                          Build Id:20150219-0600

Comment: Yes  .Firewall is there.I am not able to access "this file".Any other option to solve this

Comment: Also not [this file via HTTPS](https://master.dl.sourceforge.net/project/red-robot-editor/repository/compositeContent.xml)? Eclipse needs access to this file to install the plugin. If HTTPS does not work also, is there someone you can ask to get access to this website?

Comment: I get a 503 error but I can download the composite XML from a browser no problem. Any ideas why the eclipse marketplace tool can't reach source forge? I launch the program as my user from a terminal and don't see any errors.